# fail compile if required flags aren't present

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have some legacy code that needs certain gcc flags passed in.  Can I add pre-processor checks for these flags?

For example, let's say I need `-fno-strict-aliasing`, can I do something like this:

```
#ifndef _FNO_STRICT_ALIASING
   #error -fno-strict-aliasing is required!
#endif
```

Comment: sounds like something make should be able to do.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Of course the flag can be passed in via make. But if the source code moves to a new make system that knowledge can be lost (for example, if you're distributing the source to a lib).  I want the code itself to know what it needs.  It's more DRY that way. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
#pragma GCC optimize "no-strict-aliasing"
```

to compile the file with that flag (overriding what was specified on the command line).
You can also use

```
__attribute__((optimize("no-strict-aliasing")))
```

to apply the flag to a single function within a source file...

Comment: Ah! Even better than what I was asking for!

Comment: It would be better still to fix your broken code that requires this flag, so that it's actually valid C.

Comment: Oh no: using pragma with no-strict-aliasing doesn't work:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=486176

Comment: @R.. Of course, but we don't often have control over whether the code can be changed. In my case, the code is generated by SWIG.

Comment: SWIG is open source, and I bet the author would accept patches...  :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely no #define for it, at least on my version of GCC.

To see all predefined preprocessor symbols:

```
g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

I do not think there is any way to test these options.  However, if you are using GCC 4.4 or later, you can use the ["optimize" function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007boptimize_007d-function-attribute-2477) or the ["optimize" #pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#index-pragma-GCC-optimize-3243) to enable specific options on a per-function or per-file basis.

For example, if you add this to a common header file:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#pragma GCC optimize ("no-strict-aliasing")
#else
#error "You are not using GCC"
#endif
```

...it should enable the option for every file that includes the header.

[update]

OK so it took me about 10 minutes too long to compose this answer.  I am going to leave it here anyway for the links to the GCC docs.

Comment: Oh no: using pragma with no-strict-aliasing doesn't work:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=486176